# Visibility linker warnings when compiling iOS app that uses Boost

Tags: ios, xcode, boost, linker, clang

My iOS app uses a library which in turn depends on Boost. While revamping the 3rdparty build system, I encountered linker warnings such as this

```
ld: warning: direct access in ___cxx_global_var_init to global weak symbol
std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream()
means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime.
This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

and this

```
ld: warning: direct access in __GLOBAL__I_a to global weak symbol
boost::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()
means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime.
This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

I saw that there are quite a few other questions on SO regarding this warning. I followed their advice and made sure that the visibility settings in all builds are the same (`-fvisibility=hidden` and `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`). After a full rebuild I still got the warnings.

Environment:

- Xcode 4.6.0
- iOS SDK 6.1
- Building Boost using a modified clone of the popular [galbraithjosephs-boostoniphone](https://gitorious.org/boostoniphone/galbraithjosephs-boostoniphone) build script
- Boost version 1.54.0
- Building with `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the Boost build script used `clang++` as the compiler, but the other library and my own iOS app used `clang` (the other library and my app are Xcode projects where builds are made with `clang`).

The warnings disappeared after I rebuilt Boost with `clang`.

The sad thing is that I don't know exactly why this helped. I am aware that compiling with `clang++` switches the compiler into C++ mode, turning on/off certain settings. But it certainly can't mean that using `clang++` overrides visibility settings that are *explicitly* specified on the command line?! Comments or additional answers explaining the behaviour are welcome.