# Several warnings generated on compiling with POCO library

Tags: xcode, poco, poco-libraries

There are plenty of warnings when compiling a xcode project that is linked to static POCO libraries. The Version of Poco is 1.6.0; XCode version is 6.3.2; OSX SDK version is: 10.10. How to resolve this? Any help would be appreciable.

```
ld: warning: direct access in Poco::Dynamic::VarHolderImpl<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::convert(bool&) const 
to global weak symbol guard variable for Poco::Dynamic::VarHolderImpl<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::convert(bool&) const::VAL_INT_FALSE 
means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

Comment: It seems that you have to [set Symbols Hidden by Default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685045/xcode-with-boost-linkerid-warning-about-visibility-settings) to YES. You may also check if you [use clang++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190458/visibility-linker-warnings-when-compiling-ios-app-that-uses-boost) for your application.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks but setting Symbols Hidden to YES doesnot solve the problem.